# how to create a table layout with float in css

Tags: css

I want to create 3 divs inside outer div.The outer div is 72%.The three inner span with classes **first,second,third** should be 24%.

```
   <div id="outer">
   <div id="inner">
      <div class="content">
      <span class="first">
      HELLO
      </span>
      </div>

    <div class="content">
      <span class="second">
      pRERNA
          </span>
      </div>

   <div class="content">
      <span class="third">
      gOLANI
       </span>
    </div>
```

css

```
#inner
   {
      width:72%;   
   }

    div.content span.first
    {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        width:33%;

    }
    div.content span.second
    {
        clear:left;
        display:block;
        float:right;
        width:33%;

    }
```

I want to do this with the help of **float** property of css

Comment: Why only `float`? Did you try the `display: table-*` properties?

Comment: no it is requirement to use float only.

Comment: A percentage width is a percentage of the parent element's width.

Comment: no actually i want a table structure 72% divided into 3 columns to give 24%

Comment: please up vote I am unable to post questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of the spans and give the first second and third divs a class of "content" and then in your css put: `.content { float: left; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Scrap the `span`, assign a class to all 3 divs instead, then use `float:` on the class. If this doesn't work, you might have an easier time with `display: table-`.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp