# css float with width percentage

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create a table layout with float in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526261/how-to-create-a-table-layout-with-float-in-css)

```
    #inner
{

 height:700px;

    }
div.content
{   
    float:left;
  width:95%;

}
    div.content span.first
    {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        width:25%;
        overflow:hidden;

    }
    div.content span.second
    {
        clear:both;
        display:block;
        float:right;
         width:25%;

    }
    div.content span.third
    {
        clear:both;
        display:block;
        float:right;
        width:25%;

    }
</style>
```

```
<body>

    <div id="outer">
          <div id="inner">
          <div class="content">
            <span class="first">
           HELLO
        </span>
       </div>

    <div class="content">
      <span class="second">
      pRERNA
          </span>
      </div>

   <div class="content">
      <span class="third">
      gOLANI
       </span>
    </div>
```

When working with pixels is working but not with percentage why?I want to  create three columns of equal width.If outer element is 72%.I want to create cloumns of 72/3 ie 24% width.

Comment: please explain what you are asking a little better so more people can help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a width to the parent. Whether that's 100% or a pixel width otherwise the engine doesn't know what to derive the % from.

also you should explain what your code is doing and what you want it to do better so that more people can help and you don't get down votes :)

edit

also considering what you're showing here you probably are ending up with children going outside of the INNER parent. I would add a clearfix to your stylesheets just google clearfix and you should be good to go. Basically it adds a pseudo element to the end of the parent, clears that element, which gives a context so your children play nicely.