# Header doesn't go across entire page

Tags: css, header

I'm trying to make my header go across the entire page. I read the CSS Full Page Width Header and Header in CSS that goes across the page posts, & I tried part of the Header in CSS... using the width: 1004px; Didn't work. I've also tried width 100%. I've been reading all afternoon and don't know what to do. I hope I'm not sending unnecessary code.
Thank you

```
<html>
<head>    
    <title>some text</title>

    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">
            <img class="logo" src="file:///Users/janedoe/CGT136as/week07hw/website/images/lily-pads.jpg" alt="Admin Extraordinaire"  />           
        </div><!--/#header-->

    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Read Our Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/#nav--> 
   </div><!--/#container-->

</body>
</html>
```

/* BODY AND CONTAINER
---------------------------------*/

```
body { 
    font-size: 76%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#container { 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}



 /* HEADER AREA
    ---------------------------------*/
    #header {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: #baaf07;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `div#container` has a fixed width. Try changing it to `100%` like this:

```
#container { 
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wmhAd/

Answer (score 0):

You have the header inside of the container which has a `width: 900px;`

```
#container { 
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

You will have to place the header outside of that div and it will be 100%.

You could also give it `position: absolute;` with a `left: 0;` and `top: 0;`.

Comment: Thank you. When you say place the header outside of that div, do you mean put the #header before #container?

Comment: Yeah that would be the best result unless you want that content inside of the header?

Comment: That did not work for me. Maybe I had some traced of old code. I will try that again. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem and the best of luck to you mate.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a width of 100% to a floating container. That's not going to work.
Remove `float: left` from `#header`.

Comment: `width` can be applied to floated elements. But in this context, I agree: there's no need to float the `#header`.

Comment: Only fixed width can be applied to floated elements. Percentages won't help. As far as I recall, at least.

Comment: @showdev, first, thanks for the `jsfiddle` tip! wonderful tool. Second, well, I guess I'll have to stand corrected. I seem to recall that percentage-based width for floating elements would only work if the parent has a set width... as explained here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11527740/443716

Answer (score 0):

Your container has a limited with (900px). Because your header is inside of the container, it's also limited to that with. By adding `position: absolute` to your header, it ignores the restrictions of the container. Then you need to add `left: 0` to make sure the header starts on the left of the page.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/mpuGY/)**

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #baaf07;
}
```