# create 3 by 3 matrix using float in css

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create a table layout with float in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526261/how-to-create-a-table-layout-with-float-in-css)

I want to create 3 by 3 matrix using float property of css.The colums must be of equal heifht and width and be cross browser compactible.I want the height of colums must be the height of largest column in a row

**CSS**

```
   div.outer
 {
   width:700px;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
  }


div.inner
{
   width:700px;
  float:left;
  position:relative;

}


div.content
{  width:700px;
   float:left;
   position:relative;

}
span.std
{
  width:500px;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
span.std span.std-content
{
   float:left;
   width:250px;
   position:relative;


 }
```

**Code**

```
<div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
    <span class="std">
    <span class="std-content">
       Column 1 Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1Column 1</p>

    </span>
    <span class="std-content">
          Column 2


    </span>
    </span>

    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What problems are you seeing with this code? Why do you have to use `float`?

Comment: looks like a eligible use of a table...

Comment: for one you spelled 'position' wrong in your first CSS item

Comment: This is weird on SO that people Downvote without explaination. If you are downvoting any question or answer please add a comment explaining why you downvoted

Comment: Can you give us an image of what you want to achieve, the description isn't very helpful and that code won't produce a 3x3 grid at all. You were given a perfectly useful answer for exactly what your initial question was except you just don't to use that. If we don't know what you're after we can't really give you help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work in all browsers.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/K9bjX/

#### Output

[image: grid]

#### HTML

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
<div>​
```

#### CSS

```css
#grid {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;        
}

.cell {
    outline: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;    
}
```